# pandas のデータ処理の高速化　と　表作成方法

Tags: python, pandas

以下のpythonのコードは、生産管理システムから取得したデータを「手順」「号機」で分類して
作業時間を求めています。作業は３つの手順からなり、開始日時と終了日時の差分が作業時間になりますが、中断があるので累積させる必要があります。

やりたいことは以下２つです。
１つ目：もっと高速に「手順」別、「号機」別の作業時間の算出と累積時間の算出はできないでしょうか？２重のforループとなっているのはあまりスマートではなさそうです。えらく時間がかかります。
２つ目：画像のような横軸が号機、縦軸が手順でセルには累積時間をセットした表を作成したいのですが方法が分かりません。リスト内辞書を作って、DataFrameに出来るかなとも思ったのですが
ここからが分かりませんでした。

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

DF=ps.DataFrame(columns=['手順名','状態','開始日時','終了日時','号機'])
Items=[
    ['手順1','中断','2019-6-28 08:15:00','2019-6-28 08:16:00','1'],
    ['手順1','中断','2019-6-28 08:16:30','2019-6-28 08:17:30','1'],
    ['手順1','完成','2019-6-28 08:18:30','2019-6-28 08:19:30','1'],
    ['手順2','中断','2019-6-28 08:20:30','2019-6-28 08:21:30','1'],
    ['手順2','完成','2019-6-28 08:22:30','2019-6-28 08:23:30','1'],
    ['手順3','中断','2019-6-28 08:24:30','2019-6-28 08:25:30','1'],
    ['手順3','完成','2019-6-28 08:26:30','2019-6-28 08:27:30','1'],
    ['手順1','中断','2019-6-28 08:30:00','2019-6-28 08:31:00','2'],
    ['手順1','中断','2019-6-28 08:31:30','2019-6-28 08:32:30','2'],
    ['手順1','完成','2019-6-28 08:33:30','2019-6-28 08:34:30','2'],
    ['手順2','中断','2019-6-28 08:35:30','2019-6-28 08:36:30','2'],
    ['手順2','完成','2019-6-28 08:37:30','2019-6-28 08:38:30','2'],
    ['手順3','中断','2019-6-28 08:39:30','2019-6-28 08:40:30','2'],
    ['手順3','完成','2019-6-28 08:41:30','2019-6-28 08:42:30','2']
]
for i,Dat in enumerate(Items[::-1]):
    DF.loc[i]=Dat

list_手順と号機=[]

for name,group in DF.groupby('手順名'):
    df_時間sort = group.sort_values(by=['開始日時'],ascending=[True])
    for name2,group2 in df_時間sort.groupby('号機'):
        group2['作業時間'] = pd.to_datetime(group2['終了日時'])-pd.to_datetime(group2['開始日時'])
        group2['累積時間'] = group2['作業時間'].cumsum()
        list_手順と号機.append({'手順名':name,'号機':name2,'時間':group2['累積時間'].max()})
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
画像のセル中の時間はあくまで例です。適当な値が入っています。

Comment: コードを見やすくしました。失礼いたしました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list_手順と号機=[]`以後の部分を以下に置き換えればプログラムはすっきりするでしょう。
処理時間が速くなるか、については質問に提示されたプログラムがそのままではWindowsのPython3.7.3+pandas0.24.2で動作しなかったので分かりませんが、2重forループより少しは速くなるのではないでしょうか。

```
DF = DF.sort_values(['号機','手順名','開始日時'])
DFdelta = DF.assign(作業時間 = (pd.to_datetime(DF['終了日時']) - pd.to_datetime(DF['開始日時'])))
DFsum = DFdelta.pivot_table(index=['手順名'], columns=['号機'], values=['作業時間'], aggfunc='sum')
DFsum = DFsum.rename(columns={'作業時間': '累積時間'})
DFsum = DFsum.rename_axis('手順', axis='index')
```

処理後の`print(DFsum)`の表示は以下になります。

```
        累積時間
号機         1        2
手順
手順1 00:03:00 00:03:00
手順2 00:02:00 00:02:00
手順3 00:02:00 00:02:00
```

なお、`DF=ps.DataFrame`の **`ps`** は **`pd`** のtypoですね。

Comment: ご指導ありがとうございます。とてもきれいなコードですごいです。kunifさんはコードを書く際はどんなことを注意されているのでしょうか？for文を使わないといった自分なりの哲学があるのでしょうか？何か注意点があれば教えてください。

Comment: pandasが高機能で、複雑な繰り返し処理が簡潔に書けるのと、プログラムの量そのものは少なかったので、色々工夫を試せたからです。他では普通にforの多重ループとかifの組み合わせ条件とか使います。時間に余裕があれば、出来るようになったら嬉しい使い方をキーワードに検索して知識を増やしておくのが良いでしょう。

Comment: kunif様、ご指導ありがとうございます。大変勉強になりました。